# How to access selected row in a AlloyUI Data Table

Tags: javascript, alloy-ui, yui-datatable

Im using AlloyUI 3.0.
I used the code above:

```
YUI().use(
    'aui-datatable',
    function(Y) {
        var columns = [
            {label: 'ID', key: 'id'},
            {label: 'Project Name', key: 'name'},
            {label: 'Created At', key: 'created_at'}
        ],
        data = [];

        var myDataTable = new Y.DataTable({
            plugins: [
                {
                    cfg: {
                    selectRow: true
                },
                fn: Y.Plugin.DataTableSelection
                },
                {
                cfg: {
                    highlightRange: false,
                    type: 'rows'
                },
                fn: Y.Plugin.DataTableHighlight
                }
            ],
            columns: columns,
            data: data
        })
        .render("#myDataTable");
    }
);
```

How to get the selected row data?
How to define the selection event, click, double click, etc?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:
    var rowUID = DataTable.get('selection').rows[0].guid();
    DataTable.getRecord(uid).toJSON();